# Dunno how to put asynctask code into game

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I did a simple game of ball and onTouchListener. However, the game runs very slow because it draws every 50 milseconds the screen -.- so I am trying to use AsyncTask but I dunno how to actually draw with it.
If anyone could explain what to write or write the correct code I'll be grateful.

Here's the complete code:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
OurView v;
Bitmap ball;
float x,y;
Bitmap a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = new OurView(this);

    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.blueball);
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2;
    y = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2;
    setContentView(v);


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    v.pause();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}


public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread tr = null;
    boolean isItOk = false;
    SurfaceHolder holder;

    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(isItOk)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255,5,5,10);
            c.drawBitmap(ball,x-(ball.getWidth()/2),y-ball.getHeight()/2,null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

    }

    public void pause(){
        isItOk = false;

        while(true){
            try{
                tr.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        }
        tr = null;
    }

    public void resume(){
        isItOk = true;
        tr = new Thread(this);
        tr.start();
    }


}
```

}

```
public class Hey extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> implements View.OnTouchListener
```

{

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();



}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ball.x= event.getX();
            ball.y = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ball.x = event.getX();
            ball.y = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            ball.x = event.getX();
            ball.y = event.getY();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that's a total misuse of AsyncTask.  Not every function in an AsyncTask runs on another thread-  only doInBackground does.  So in your onTouch function, you're sleeping the main thread for 50ms on every touch down, up, and move.  Yeah, your code is going to run like shit.  If you want to rate limit your drawing, you want to do it in the run loop of your surface holder's thread, not when processing input.

Comment: Ok, so I will put .sleep for the run loop of the main thread. But as for my question - how do I put an async mothod in the main ui? I searched for hours on the internet and I only find the methods for this class and not how to use them.